# Private VBA Class Initializer called from Factory #2

Tags: vba, classes, factory-method

**About**

This is a follow-up of a previous question [Private VBA Class Initializer called from Factory](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250578/private-vba-class-initializer-called-from-factory). I've decided to create a new question instead of answering my old question because I would like the community to review and possibly suggest improvements on the new improved code.

VBA Class methods are always called with an instance pointer but the implementation is hidden and managed by VBA. If we can manipulate that specific instance pointer then we can access methods from instance B of a class directly from instance A (of the same class type) even if those methods are declared as Private. The previous question does exactly that but in a crude, slow and unsafe way. This question will cover a better approach (in my humble view).

For example, a method of a class might look like this in VBA:

```
Public Sub Test(ByVal arg1)
```

but the method is actually implemented more like this:

```
Public Sub Test(this As LongPtr, ByVal arg1)
```

The code presented in this question replaces the `this` pointer with another instance pointer (directly in memory) and thus allows inter-instance calls.

**The `Me` keyword**

Before we continue, let's clarify what the `Me` keyword is. `Me` behaves as a locally-scoped variable to any class method but in reality it is implemented as a hidden `Property Get` that is reading the above mentioned `this` pointer (which is locally scoped because it was passed as an argument to the class method). This is easy to check:

Code inside a `SomeClass` class:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
    Dim tempPtr As LongPtr

    ptr1 = LibMemory.MemLongPtr(VarPtr(Me)) 'Me is still within scope while memory is read
    ptr2 = LibMemory.MemLongPtr(VarPtr(Me)) 'Me is still within scope while memory is read
    Debug.Assert ptr1 = ptr2 'Same address so code does not stop
    
    tempPtr = VarPtr(Me) 'Me gets out of scope after assignment
    ptr3 = LibMemory.MemLongPtr(tempPtr) 'Me is not is scope anymore
    Debug.Assert ptr1 = ptr3 'ptr3 is 0
End Sub
```

Code in a standard module:

```
Sub TestME()
    Dim c As New SomeClass
    c.Test
End Sub
```

By running the `TestME` method, the second `Assert` within the class instance will fail because `Me` got out of scope. This suggests that `Me` is actually a `Property Get` or a `Function` rather than a locally-scoped variable. Hence, we cannot use `Me` to get to `this`.

Notice that I am not using the well-known `CopyMemory` API. Instead I am using a `LibMemory` library that I have created specifically for this question. `LibMemory` can be found at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252659/fast-native-memory-manipulation-in-vba) and [GitHub](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools). The CR question explains the reasoning behind the library.

**The Code**

First of all, we need the above-mentioned `LibMemory`

We also need a class that encapsulates all the logic for redirecting class instances.
Code inside `InstanceRedirector` class:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type INSTANCE_REDIRECT
    #If VBA7 Then
        swapAddress As LongPtr
        originalPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
        swapAddress As Long
        originalPtr As Long
    #End If
    targetInstance As Object 'Keep a reference until restore is called
End Type

Private this As INSTANCE_REDIRECT

'*******************************************************************************
'Redirects the instance of a class to another instance of the same class
'This method must be called from a class instance's Function (not Sub)
'
'Warning! RestoreInstance must be called before the calling function goes out
'   of scope OR this instance must be terminated so that RestoreInstance is
'   called at Class_Terminate
'
'Warning! vbArray + vbString Function return type is not supported. It would be
'   possible to find the correct address by reading memory in a loop but there
'   would be no checking available
'*******************************************************************************
#If VBA7 Then
Public Sub Redirect(ByVal funcReturnPtr As LongPtr, ByVal currentInstance As Object, ByVal targetInstance As Object)
#Else
Public Sub Redirect(ByVal funcReturnPtr As Long, ByVal currentInstance As Object, ByVal targetInstance As Object)
#End If
    Const methodName As String = "Redirect"
    '
    'Validate Input
    If currentInstance Is Nothing Or targetInstance Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, TypeName(Me) & "." & methodName, "Object not set"
    ElseIf TypeName(currentInstance) <> TypeName(targetInstance) Then
        Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me) & "." & methodName, "Expected same interface"
    ElseIf funcReturnPtr = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me) & "." & methodName, "Missing Func Return Ptr"
    End If
    '
    'Store original pointer
    this.originalPtr = ObjPtr(GetDefaultInterface(currentInstance))
    '
    'On x64 the shadow stack space is allocated next to the Function Return
    'On x32 the stack space has a fixed offset (found through testing)
    #If Win64 Then
        Const memOffsetNonVariant As LongLong = LibMemory.PTR_SIZE
        Const memOffsetVariant As LongLong = LibMemory.PTR_SIZE * 3
    #Else
        Const memOffsetNonVariant As Long = LibMemory.PTR_SIZE * 28
        Const memOffsetVariant As Long = LibMemory.PTR_SIZE * 31
    #End If
    '
    'Try Non-Variant func return first and then Variant if the former fails
    If Not SetSwapAddress(funcReturnPtr, memOffsetNonVariant) Then
        SetSwapAddress funcReturnPtr, memOffsetVariant
    End If
    '
    If this.swapAddress = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me) & "." & methodName, "Invalid input or " _
        & "not called from class function or vbArray + vbString func return type"
    End If
    '
    'Keep a reference until restore is called, for extra safety
    Set this.targetInstance = GetDefaultInterface(targetInstance)
    '
    'Redirect Instance
    LibMemory.MemLongPtr(this.swapAddress) = ObjPtr(this.targetInstance)
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
'Finds and sets the swap address (address of the instance pointer on the stack)
'*******************************************************************************
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function SetSwapAddress(ByRef funcReturnPtr As LongPtr, ByRef memOffset As LongPtr) As Boolean
#Else
Private Function SetSwapAddress(ByRef funcReturnPtr As Long, ByRef memOffset As Long) As Boolean
#End If
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim tempPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim tempPtr As Long
    #End If
    '
    tempPtr = LibMemory.UnsignedAddition(funcReturnPtr, memOffset)
    #If Win64 Then
    #Else
        tempPtr = UnsignedAddition(MemLongPtr(tempPtr), PTR_SIZE * 2)
    #End If
    If LibMemory.MemLongPtr(tempPtr) = this.originalPtr Then
        this.swapAddress = tempPtr
        SetSwapAddress = True
    End If
End Function

'*******************************************************************************
'Returns the default interface for an object
'Casting from IUnknown to IDispatch (Object) forces a call to QueryInterface for
'   the IDispatch interface (which knows about the default interface)
'*******************************************************************************
Private Function GetDefaultInterface(obj As IUnknown) As Object
    Set GetDefaultInterface = obj
End Function

'*******************************************************************************
'Restores the original instance pointer at the previously used swap address
'*******************************************************************************
Public Sub Restore()
    If this.swapAddress = 0 Or this.originalPtr = 0 Then Exit Sub
    LibMemory.MemLongPtr(this.swapAddress) = this.originalPtr
    this.swapAddress = 0
    this.originalPtr = 0
    Set this.targetInstance = Nothing
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
'Extra safety in case .Restore is not called
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Restore
End Sub
```

Notice that this code has a lot of checks in place compared to the previous CR question which was only reading memory in a loop until a specific value was found. Moreover, the exact location is found using predefined memory offsets.

**Demo**

Consider a `Class1` which has `VB_PredeclaredId` set to True:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private m_id As Long

Public Function Factory(ByVal newID As Long) As Class1
    Dim c As New Class1
    '
    With New InstanceRedirector
        .Redirect VarPtr(Factory), Me, c
        Init newID
        .Restore 'This can be ommited within a With New block (Class_Terminate calls it anyway)
    End With
    Set Factory = c
End Function
Private Sub Init(newID As Long)
    m_id = newID
End Sub

Public Function Factory2(ByVal newID As Long) As Class1
    Dim c As New Class1
    '
    c.Init2 newID
    Set Factory2 = c
End Function
Public Sub Init2(newID As Long)
    m_id = newID
End Sub

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = m_id
End Property
```

The `Factory` method uses a private `Init` method while the `Factory2` uses a public `Init2` method.

Quick speed test in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFactorySpeeds()
    Const loopsCount As Long = 100000
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t As Double
    '
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To loopsCount
        Debug.Assert Class1.Factory2(i).ID = i
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Public  Init (seconds): " & VBA.Round(Timer - t, 3)
    '
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To loopsCount
        Debug.Assert Class1.Factory(i).ID = i
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Private  Init (seconds): " & VBA.Round(Timer - t, 3)
End Sub
```

In general the Private method seems to be only 3x slower but the benefit of accessing private methods seems to be worth the speed loss.

**Notes**

Obviously, the demo above shows how to create a Factory that is using a Private Init but the approach presented here allows any class instance (Predeclared or not) to access private methods within other instances of the same class type. A good idea provided by @TinMan in the previous question is to create a class `Clone` method.

The return value of the class function where the redirection is used does not necessarily need to be an Object. It can be any data type (except an Array of String i.e. vbArray + vbString VarType). For return types of Array type, the `VarPtrArray` function from the `LibMemory` library can be used for the first argument when calling InstanceRedirector.Redirect.

The class method where the redirection is used/called needs to be a `Function` and not a `Sub` because the function return will be allocated on the call stack and we can use it's address to find the actual memory location of the class instance pointer.

On x64 the instance pointer is allocated on the call stack immediately after the function return while on x32 there is a fixed offset and a redirection. If the function return type is of type Variant then the offsets are increased by two ptr positions on x64 (i.e. + 16 bytes) and three ptr positions on x32 (i.e. + 12 bytes).

**Question(s)**

I would be very grateful for suggestions that could improve the code in any way (speed, readability, structure, naming etc.).

---

**EDIT #1**

If an unexpected error occurs while the `Init` method is running then the whole application will crash because `.Restore` gets called too late.

Obviously, this code (see demo `Class1` in the original question):

```
With New InstanceRedirector
    .Redirect VarPtr(Factory), Me, c
    Init newID
    .Restore
End With
```

can be replaced with something like:

```
With New InstanceRedirector
    .Redirect VarPtr(Factory), Me, c
    On Error Resume Next
    Init newID
    .Restore
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Do whatever
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

but we now have boilerplate code that we would need to remember to copy everytime we want to use the redirection capability within a class.

However, the instance pointer does not need to be restored if we don't use the redirection inside the first method called on a class (e.g. the public `Factory` method in the example).

If we use the redirection inside any class method that is called from another method of the same class then it's safe to skip restoring the instance pointer. No error handling is required to prevent any crashes. Moreover, there is no need to have a separate class for the redirection. A simple method inside a .bas module will suffice.

The best place to make the redirection is in the private method that will need the redirection. Makes perfect sense - it will always be called from another method of the same class. The code in the original example could leave the reader wondering what is happenin in the private `Init` method but doing the redirection within the `Init` is much more readable anyway.

The code in the original question had some alignment issues on x32 when the return value of the function was less/more than 4 bytes in size. If we fix that then consider this minimal code for redirection (in a standard .bas module):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'*******************************************************************************
'Redirects the instance of a class to another instance of the same class within
'   the scope of a class Function (not  Sub) where the call happens.
'
'Warning! ONLY call this method from a Private Function of a class!
'
'vbArray + vbString Function return type is not supported. It would be
'   possible to find the correct address by reading memory in a loop but there
'   would be no checking available
'*******************************************************************************
#If Win64 Then
Public Sub RedirectInstance(ByVal funcReturnPtr As LongLong _
                          , ByVal currentInstance As Object _
                          , ByVal targetInstance As Object)
#Else
Public Sub RedirectInstance(ByVal funcReturnPtr As Long _
                          , ByVal currentInstance As Object _
                          , ByVal targetInstance As Object)
#End If
    Const methodName As String = "RedirectInstance"
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim originalPtr As LongLong
        Dim newPtr As LongLong
        Dim swapAddress As LongLong
    #Else
        Dim originalPtr As Long
        Dim newPtr As Long
        Dim swapAddress As Long
    #End If
    '
    originalPtr = ObjPtr(GetDefaultInterface(currentInstance))
    newPtr = ObjPtr(GetDefaultInterface(targetInstance))
    '
    'Validate Input
    If currentInstance Is Nothing Or targetInstance Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, methodName, "Object not set"
    ElseIf MemLongPtr(originalPtr) <> MemLongPtr(newPtr) Then 'Faster to compare vTables than to compare TypeName(s)
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Expected same VB class"
    ElseIf funcReturnPtr = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Missing Function Return Pointer"
    End If
    '
    'On x64 the shadow stack space is allocated next to the Function Return
    'On x32 the stack space has a fixed offset (found through testing)
    #If Win64 Then
        Const memOffsetNonVariant As LongLong = PTR_SIZE
        Const memOffsetVariant As LongLong = PTR_SIZE * 3
    #Else
        Const memOffsetNonVariant As Long = PTR_SIZE * 28
        Const memOffsetVariant As Long = PTR_SIZE * 31
    #End If
    '
    swapAddress = FindSwapAddress(funcReturnPtr, memOffsetNonVariant, originalPtr)
    If swapAddress = 0 Then
        swapAddress = FindSwapAddress(funcReturnPtr, memOffsetVariant, originalPtr)
        If swapAddress = 0 Then
            Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid input or not called " _
            & "from class Function or vbArray + vbString function return type"
        End If
    End If
    '
    'Redirect Instance
    MemLongPtr(swapAddress) = newPtr
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
'Finds the swap address (address of the instance pointer on the stack)
'*******************************************************************************
#If Win64 Then
Private Function FindSwapAddress(ByVal funcReturnPtr As LongLong _
                               , ByVal memOffset As LongLong _
                               , ByVal originalPtr As LongLong) As LongLong
    Dim swapAddr As LongLong: swapAddr = funcReturnPtr + memOffset
    If MemLongLong(swapAddr) = originalPtr Then
        FindSwapAddress = swapAddr
    End If
End Function
#Else
Private Function FindSwapAddress(ByVal funcReturnPtr As Long _
                               , ByVal memOffset As Long _
                               , ByVal originalPtr As Long) As Long
    Dim startAddr As Long: startAddr = funcReturnPtr + memOffset
    Dim swapAddr As Long
    '
    'Adjust memory alignment for Boolean/Byte/Integer function return type
    startAddr = startAddr - (startAddr Mod PTR_SIZE)
    '
    swapAddr = GetSwapIndirectAddress(startAddr)
    If swapAddr = 0 Then
        'Adjust mem alignment for Currency/Date/Double function return type
        swapAddr = GetSwapIndirectAddress(startAddr + PTR_SIZE)
        If swapAddr = 0 Then Exit Function
    End If
    If MemLongPtr(swapAddr) = originalPtr Then
        FindSwapAddress = swapAddr
    End If
End Function
Private Function GetSwapIndirectAddress(ByVal startAddr As Long) As Long
    Const maxOffset As Long = PTR_SIZE * 100
    Dim swapAddr As Long: swapAddr = MemLong(startAddr) + PTR_SIZE * 2
    '
    'Check if the address is within acceptable limits. The address
    '   of the instance pointer (within the stack frame) cannot be too far
    '   from the function return address (first offsetted to startAddr)
    If startAddr < swapAddr And swapAddr - startAddr < maxOffset * PTR_SIZE Then
        GetSwapIndirectAddress = swapAddr
    End If
End Function
#End If

'*******************************************************************************
'Returns the default interface for an object
'Casting from IUnknown to IDispatch (Object) forces a call to QueryInterface for
'   the IDispatch interface (which knows about the default interface)
'*******************************************************************************
Private Function GetDefaultInterface(ByVal obj As IUnknown) As Object
    Set GetDefaultInterface = obj
End Function
```

The code will work even if an error is raised within the `Init` method. Will work means that only runtime error will be raised but no crash will occur.

The `DemoClass` would look like this:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private m_id As Long

Public Function Factory(ByVal newID As Long) As DemoClass
    Dim c As New DemoClass
    Init c, newID
    Set Factory = c
End Function

Private Function Init(ByVal c As DemoClass, ByVal newID As Long) As Boolean
    RedirectInstance VarPtr(Init), Me, c
    m_id = newID
End Function

Public Function Factory2(ByVal newID As Long) As Class1
    Dim c As New Class1
    '
    c.Init2 newID
    Set Factory2 = c
End Function
Public Sub Init2(newID As Long)
    m_id = newID
End Sub

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = m_id
End Property
```

Since the `RedirectInstance` method is using [LibMemory](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools) then it makes sense to have it within the same memory module. Repository will be updated soon.

Finally, removing the need for restoring the instance pointer and the instantiation of a new class makes this faster. A private init is now only 1.75x slower than the public counterpart as opposed to 3x slower with the class/restore approach.

I guess the only risk here is that the redirection can be called from a method that is not private. I don't think it's possible to force the user to use a private method. I also don't think there is an easy way to check if the calling method is private. So, the only warning is the comment above the method definition.

Comment: This is really cool, am quite amazed this is doable. Never knew it was part of your memory module either!

Comment: @Sancarn Thanks! I added quite a bit of useful stuff to the library. Happy to add more if you have any ideas.